# finding the actions of semidirect products in GAP

Tags: gap

I am a newbie in GAP, and I couldn't find how one can find the action of a semi direct product in GAP. Can anyone help me with it?

More specifically, I am working with `SmallGroup(720,774)`. GAP tells me that the group structure is $((C_3 \times (C_{15} \rtimes C_4)) \rtimes C_2) \rtimes C_2$, and I would like to know the actions of the three semi-direct products in the structure.

Thanks